# mysql trigger: after insert, +1 depending on what is entered?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `grade3` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `inventory`
--

INSERT INTO `inventory` (`id`, `owner`, `grade1`, `grade2`, `grade3`) VALUES
(3, 1, 2, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `transfer`
--

CREATE TABLE `transfer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` char(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `transfer`
--

INSERT INTO `transfer` (`id`, `owner`, `total`) VALUES
(20, 1, 1);

--
-- Triggers `transfer`
--
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `t` AFTER INSERT ON `transfer` FOR EACH ROW update inventory t1
set t1.grade1 = t1.grade1 + 1
WHERE t1.owner = new.owner
AND `total` = '/1'
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have two tables as you can see from above code. I am in the process of using triggers in MySQL.

What I am trying to do, is that when someone enters something into transfer, and the owner matches the owner which is in the inventory- if what they have typed '(a number)/1' into total in transfer, it would add 1 to grade1. If they typed in '(a number)/2' into total, it will add 1 to grade2. And same for grade3. As you can see from the trigger above, this is what I have tried. I have tried it without the `` AND `total` = '/1' `` so I know the issue must be within that part. I have also tried without the ` around total, however it doesn't recognise this column without it.

I've had a look through SO and cannot find anything to resolve this.

I need this section done through a trigger- if anyone has any idea, can they please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for posting the dump of your tables and sample data. Kudos for that, most posts don't have that information. However, I don't understand what you're trying to do with the trigger. What does it mean for an integer `total` to be `'/1'`? You don't have that kind of information, because the `total` is just an integer, not a string.

Comment: Ah! Sorry! I didn't even notice that. Have now changed to Varchar. Does it make sense of what i need other than that? Thanks

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Indeed it does! Exactly how I need, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you really need is a fourth column `grade` in the `transfer` table so your trigger code can know which grade to increment. All you have in the trigger is `OLD.*` and `NEW.*`, the columns of the row that changed. You can't make one of your current integer columns carry extra information that is more than a simple integer.

```
ALTER TABLE transfer ADD COLUMN grade TINYINT UNSIGNED;
```

Then you can use this in the trigger to tell which grade to increment.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t` AFTER INSERT ON `transfer` FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE inventory
SET grade1 = grade1 + CASE NEW.grade WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    grade2 = grade2 + CASE NEW.grade WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    grade3 = grade3 + CASE NEW.grade WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
WHERE owner = NEW.owner
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to update different columns conditionally is to update all of them, but use a condition to determine whether to give them a new value or keep the old value. This can be used in a trigger just like any other `UPDATE` query.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t` AFTER INSERT ON `transfer` FOR EACH ROW update inventory t1
set t1.grade1 = IF(new.total LIKE '%/1', t1.grade1 + 1, t1.grade1),
    t1.grade2 = IF(new.total LIKE '%/2', t1.grade2 + 1, t1.grade2),
    t1.grade3 = IF(new.total LIKE '%/3', t1.grade3 + 1, t1.grade3)
WHERE t1.owner = new.owner
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! I've given this a go, and unfortunately it doesn't quite work. The Trigger is obviously correct, however whenever I add anything into transfer, it won't update dependant of what i have entered if that makes sense? I.E does not add 1 to Grade 2 if i type '2/2' etc.

Comment: `total` is an integer, how can you enter strings like `1/2`, `2/2`, `3/2`, etc?

Comment: Hi, I've now changed it to a VARCHAR

Comment: Does my answer work now? You didn't change the `INSERT` query in the question.

Comment: Why is this column called `total`? It doesn't seem like the total of anything.